# how to show selected image names inside modal using ionic and angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have used a cordova plugin to select images from a ios gallery and display the image. The problem I'm facing here is that I want a modal where the selected image names should be displayed but I'm not able to display this modal.
Here is my code:

**My controller:**

```
app.controller('ImagePickerController', function($scope, $rootScope,$cordovaImagePicker, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaContacts,$ionicModal) {
    $scope.ready = false;
    $scope.images = [];

    $scope.openGallery = function() {
        alert("hii");

        var options = {
                maximumImagesCount: 20, // Max number of selected images, I'm using only one for this example
                width: 800,
                height: 800,
                quality: 100            // Higher is better
        };

        $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options).then(function(results) {
            for(var i=0 ; i<results.length ; i++){
                //alert(results[i]);
                //console.log('img', imageUri);
                $scope.images.push(results[i]);
                var imagename = results[i];
                $scope.truncatedimgname = imagename.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
                alert(truncatedimgname);
            }

        }, function(err) {
        // error
        });

        openModal();
    };

$scope.openModal = function(animation) {
    alert("modal");
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('contact-modal.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
      $scope.modal.show();
    });
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

});
```

I have truncated the name of the image with extension inside truncatedimgname. I want my modal to be displayed when user clicks on done button after selecting images and show their names inside that modal.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `$scope.openModal()` inside the success function.
In fact `results` is available only inside this function and *asynchronously* (after selection by the user) because `$cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)` returns a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

```
$cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
    .then(function (results) {
      // on success
      ...

      openModal();
    }, function(error) {
      // on error
      ...
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your posted code, you have defined the function as `$scope.openModal` but when calling the function you have only put `openModal()` which will not find your function that is attached to the $scope variable.

You should be calling the function as `$scope.openModal();`